I have been in an interview loop for 1 month 10 days now
I cleared two interview round with one super technical assignment round for Technical product manager role.
After waiting for 10 days, I decided to follow up on a call and recruiter says everything is positive but does not send any email confirmation on the same.
Currently I am in an email thread with R1 interviewer and recruiter. Should I loop round 2 interviewer too in the followup email?
The total time this is going around is like 45 days now.

While waiting, of course, continue applying to and interviewing with other companies. A long delay is not uncommon. A silent rejection is not uncommon either. If they want you, they will get back to you eventually, but it can take months.

Unless the recruiter works directly for the company my personal advice, move on to your next opportunity, 45 days is a long time to have been selected only to not be informed of that selection

Plus, the moment you have other offers on the table you automatically have more power to negotiate better conditions. They might come back to you later only to find that you are no longer available at all or available but not with the original conditions.
